# What is the performanced best cache setting for Android Picasso?

Tags: android, performance, caching, picasso

I used this setting but it seems is not the best way. What is the best way of picasso cache setting?

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
       .load(data.getPhotoUrl())
       .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
       .into(photoUrlImageView);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Picasso Builder to set the cache size.